# NSInteger to NSString bad access exception error in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsinteger

I'm trying to make an calculator in Objective-C. I have four variables that I'm working with. They are declared in the header file as seen in this code snippet:

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface CalculatorAppViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
   NSInteger intanswer, intoperand;
   NSString *answer, *operand, *currOP;
   }


   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger intoperand;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger intanswer;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *answer;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *operand;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *currOP;

   //these are not all my variables, just the ones in question
```

Variables are brought into the implementation file through the following means:

```
   @synthesize intanswer, intoperand, answer, operand, opPressed, currOP, resultBar, clear, negpos, percent, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, divi, multi, addi, subt, enter, point;
```

I have a UILabel called resultBar that displays the the answer string variable. What I am attempting to do is gather the user input based on what he or she presses and store them into string variables (reason being if they press 1 twice, it should create 11). I then wish to take the strings in the answer and operand variables, convert them to integers, do the arithmetic, store the solution into the answer variable as a string, and display what answer now holds on the UILabel resultBar.

My main problem is that I cannot seem to convert my NSString answer variable into a NSInteger intanswer. This is a snippet of code:

```
  intanswer = [answer integerValue]; //error line, this is where the error code is
  intoperand = [operand integerValue];

  intanswer = intanswer + intoperand; 

  answer = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (NSInteger)intanswer];
  resultBar.text = answer;
```

I'm getting the Thead 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x408c5e2f) exception and I have no clue why.

Any help counts. Let me know if I can provide more information! Thank you so much :)

Comment: What exactly error says ? Are you sure it is NSString not some other class ? [NSNull null] or smth ? Put a breakpoint there and "po [answer class]" in console to see what class is it. Maybe it is UITextField - hard to tell not seeing whole project.

Comment: bad design; don't "read" from your output. your calculator should keep track of all this internally as numbers then you format the result for output.

Comment: Why show the code after the error and not the code before the error. Things like how `intanswer`is declared, the `NSLog()` of `answer`.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear in my description of my problem. I've placed some clearer information about my project. @Zaph

Comment: So is anything ever assigned to `answer`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want `strong` or preferably `copy` for `NSString` in property objects: `answer`, `operand`, `currOP` so they will not be prematurely deallocated.

You need to read-up on object lifetimes and the proper usage of `assign`, strong`and`copy`.

In this case it looks like `answer` is no longer retained and the pointer now points to garbage causing the crash. Change the 'assign' to 'copy' on the `NSString` properties.

You still need to `NSLog(@"answer: %@", answer)` and it needs to have a value.